# Access controller return value in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've returned a value from my controller.When I use the value in my view blade,it shows Syntax error
Here is my code,

Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
        $a = DB::select('select * from users where id = "$pid"', array(1));
         return view('sample', ['users' => $a]);
}
```

And in View blade,

```
 {!! Form::Id('Id', $value = {{$a}}, ['class' => 'form-control1', 'placeholder' => 'Id']) !!}
```

How 'ld I change my code,Help me

Comment: And what you want to do with `Form::Id` !!

Comment: I want to display the Id get from controller in Input field.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it wit eloquent like this :

```
public function edit($id)
{
        $a = User::find($id);
         return view('sample', ['user' => $a]);
}
```

And on top of your controller add the import :

```
use App\User;
```

In the view it's `user` that will be seen not `a` so :

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $user->id }}" />
{!! Form::email('email', $user->email, ['class' => 'form-control1', 'placeholder' => 'email']) !!}
```

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found ERROR

Comment: Try importing your User model in the controller. @saranya

Comment: I'm new to laravel,will you pls explain it

Comment: Add `use App\User` at the top of your controller !

Comment: Thanks,But it show the below error in my blade file

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\movecab\resources\views\sample.blade.php)

Comment: In  {!! Form::email('email', $value = {{$a}}, ['class' => 'form-control1', 'placeholder' => 'email']) !!}

Comment: As i said use `user` variable in the view not `a` variable !!

Comment: It shows the error in the line $user = User::find($id);

Comment: FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found

Comment: Now i've changed my code in the controller as                                      $user = User::find($id)                                                                         return view('sample', ['users' => $user]);                                                And in view as you said    {!! Form::Id('Id', $value = {{$user}}, ['class' => 'form-control1', 'placeholder' => 'Id']) !!}

Comment: @Maraboc i think you should remove '{{' '}}' in {{ $user->email }} because it is already inside '{!!'  '!!}'

Comment: I want to know what this user defines          in   $a = User::find($id);

Comment: User is the model for your table 'users'.

Comment: It's a Model as @Miggy said,   To test if it works do this `$a = User::find($id); dd($a);` and tel us what you get !!

Comment: @saranya also, you can read this documentation [laravel/eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent). Its really good.

Comment: Now I got the error             FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found
in PassengerController.php (line 55)

Comment: We told you to add `use App\User;` on top of your `PassengerController` !!

Comment: @saranya place `use App\User;` before your class. This will let you use the Model User in your Controller.

Comment: I've directly pass the data from controller to view blade and i'm not  using model

Comment: It's ok with it but you want complicate your life without need !! :)